# Are sentences containing "never" affirmative or negative?

Tags: adverbs, negation

Maybe this is a silly question: can be the sentence "I have *never* seen Singapore" be considered negative?

Comment: _Never_ is a contraction of _not ever_ 'not at any time', so yes it's negative because it contains _not_. There are [many many negative triggers](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), and many many [negative polarity items like _ever_ or _budge_ or _in weeks_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: never (ever), always, sometimes, rarely etc. are adverbs of frequency. You can take it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Never* is a negative polarity indicator.

This can easily be verified by adding a confirmatory tag question to the sentence:

> I have never seen Singapore, have I?
> I have never seen Singapore, *haven't I?

The second example, using a negative tag question, is nonsense.

Since tag questions always have the opposite polarity to the main sentence, the sentence must be negative.

Answer (score 0):

In case your intuitions about question tags aren't great, you can apply the "ain't test":

> 1. He **ain't never** coming home.
> 2. He **is never** coming home.

These two sentences mean the same thing, so "never" is considered negative.

This works because "ain't" generally doesn't negate a sentence that's already negative.